# Syslog file growing fast

Tags: java, syslog

These are the two lines constantly repeating:

```
Apr  6 09:08:44 servername audispd: node=127.0.1.1 type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1586164124.680:132340737): proctitle=2F7573722F6C69622F6A766D2F6A6176612D382D6F70656E6A646B2D616D6436396E2F6A617661002D636C61737370617468002F646174612F6469736B322F6170616368652D6E6966692F6E6966692D312E31312E312F2E2F636F6E663A2F646174612F6469736B322F6170616368652D6E6966692F6E6966692D312E
Apr  6 09:08:44 servername audispd: node=127.0.1.1 type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1586164124.680:132340738): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=no exit=-2 a0=7fed231f3290 a1=7feda03a6a50 aa0069700 a3=0 items=1 ppid=32568 pid=10734 auid=1006 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=1688 comm=54696D65722D44726976656E205072 exe="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd6bin/java" key=(null)
```

Please help to find the root cause and stop this logging.

Comment: See `/etc/audisp/audispd.conf` for configuration  of audisp.

Comment: @Rinzwind I changed action to "IGNORE" and restarted auditd and rsyslog services, it didn't help